# Якорь и JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно отследить название якоря в адресе страницы
Те http://local.ru/#ancord
Нада получить "ancord"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.hash
```

Answer (score 0):

if(window.location=='#ancord'){console.log('якорь будет получен!');}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]